# Set default display field for a model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I've got a select input referencing a model that has a 'name' field, Rails will automatically use that 'name field in the select dropdown - as the kinda pretty, default representation of a record from that model.

When I don't have a name field, it shows the raw, non-human-readable `<Postcode:0x007fbe326af930>`

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848702/rails-displaying-foreign-key-references-in-a-form) and other doco, I know I can tidy that up to display what I want in the view - but presumably there's a way to set it once and for all in the model. Like, "for this model, always use field_x as the value for select inputs, and all other situations where you want a single-field representation of a record".

How do you set the 'default display field' for a model?

Answer (score 3):

Use an `alias_attribute`.

Eg. in your model, up the top, add:

`alias_attribute :name, :field_that_is_not_name`

Comment: I don't understand how this works with `select`? Surely you'd want to create a default value for the `select` box like this: `<%= collection_select(:location, :postcode_id, Postcode.all, :id, :your_attribute) %>`

Comment: Yep, that'll work too. But by putting an alias_attribute in your model, you get it done for ALL selects you may wish to create, anywhere.