# In Rails, I'm receiving an error "Model(#-12345) expected, got String(#-12345)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I realize there's an existing question with this, but none of the answers provided worked for me. What's particularly bothersome is that I can tell I'm passing in the correct parameters through to the `create` method (or update, but I'm trying to use create for now). From the debugging/error page presented by the Rails 4 built-in server:

```
"url"=>"",
"country"=>"1",
"charge"=>"0",
```

My models are configured so that Model belongs_to Country and Country has_many Models. I don't get why, if I'm passing in properly formatted data, and I'm clearly accessing the Country model (my drop-down is populated with the appropriate names via the code below), it doesn't work. Any help is much appreciated. I'm stumped and Google has been of minimal help.

```
<%= f.select :country, Country.all.collect { |c| [c.id, c.id.to_i] }, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Also note that I've tried many variations including but not limited to:

```
<%= f.select :country, Country.all.collect { |c| [c.country_long_name, c.id] }, class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.select :country, Country.all.collect { |c| [c.id, c.id] }, class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.collection_select :country, Country.all.collect, c.country_long_name, c.id %>
```

Comment: Other relevant questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848702/rails-displaying-foreign-key-references-in-a-form
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716412/country-expected-got-string-error

Like I said, I've been through them to no avail. :(

Comment: Can you post the exact error and the line it's referencing?

Comment: Can you share more code? Your Models, Controllers, Views, where is the error happening and when?

Comment: Where're you getting the error?

Comment: You share your development  console log .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this:

I had at least a couple of issues.

First, I was not using collection select (which should be used with the dropdown form-group, BTW). This was actually mentioned in the other relevant questions that I linked to.

Second, my code had binding.pry pasted all over it as a troubleshooting tool. It's a debugging tool that lets you step through code, check variables, etc. by interrupting code execution (much like a break point in most IDE's). However, for an unknown reason, adding binding.pry was breaking my code. I would pass the results of params.require(:blah).permit(:foo, :bar) to the Burp.new() method. It was Burp.new(params.req...) that was choking. That is, I would run Burp.new(params.req...) and it would spit out an object with all the values set to nil. :'( I have no idea why it did that, but as soon as I commented out my binding.pry code, everything worked. :/

If you've found this page and are stuck like I was, I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your all aproaches were wrong. Do it as :

```
<%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.all, c.id, c.country_long_name, :prompt => true %>
```

Also, permit country_id inside your controller as
params.permit(:country_id)

Read [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) to know more about it.

Comment: In addition to above answer, add country_id in params.permit inside your controller

Comment: @AdnanDevops Thanks mentioning. I forgot to mention it. Can you edit my answer to add it..?

Comment: Done with the changes